# add action which returns modified value

Tags: actions, authentication

I want to modify submited password in [wp_logon](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/user.php#L40) `wp_authenticate` action.
When authenticating, I want to grab submited password, modify it, and pass back to [wp_logon](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/user.php#L40)

So here is an action
`do_action_ref_array('wp_authenticate', array(&$credentials['user_login'], &$credentials['user_password']));`

I'm adding my action like this (as @kaiser suggested):

```
add_action("wp_authenticate", "myfunctionhere");

function myfunctionhere($credentials) {
return $credentials['user_password'] = 'foo';
}
```

The thing is that it does not return to wp_signon.
And more, `$credentials` in `myfunctionhere` value is `string(3) "aka"` (username)

The thing I'm doing here, I want to modify http://wordpress.org/plugins/login-encryption/ plugin to work with current wordpress.

and this is the original function which was hooked on wp_authenticate

```
function add_decryption_function() {
    global $user_pass;
    if ($_REQUEST['encryption_code']) {

        // Obtenemos la clave DES usando nuestra clave privada RSA
        $key = new RSA(get_option('le_rsa_modulus'), get_option('le_rsa_public_key'), get_option('le_rsa_private_key'));
        $code = $key->decrypt($_REQUEST['encryption_code']); 

        // Obtenemos la clave usando la clave DES
        $password = des ($code, hexToString($_REQUEST['pwd']), 0, 0, null, null);
        preg_match("/^([\s\w]*)/", $password, $res);
        $user_pass = $res[1];
        $_REQUEST['encryption_code'] = "";
    }

}
```

global $user_pass is NULL of course

I'm testing native wp-login.php authentification, no other plugins.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this? That hook only takes 1 parameter passed as an array : `array(&$credentials['user_login'], &$credentials['user_password'])`, and the credentials are passed by reference `&`, so I assume you can modify it at will without any global or return.

Comment: I'm making an encryption. in fact, it already made and now I want to hook in to decrypt it. How this should work?

Comment: The more details you add to the Question ([edit]), the more chances you have to receive an adequate Answer...

Comment: @brasofilo Copy/Paste my answer (see revisions). Credits shall be yours :)

Comment: @brasofilo Sidenote: [Take a look at that link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for some nice shortcuts.

Comment: @kaiser, kein a problem, you've added more value/research. I did use the magic link `[edit]` ;)

Comment: If you are in the process of improving the question, I'd suggest getting rid of that whole core function, simply add a link to [core.track](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/user.php#L40). I think it's better to focus on *your* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work in any reasonable hack.

The only way it could work was hacking wp_logon core function itself with global variable, which was undisairable.

SO I went with another solution.

I removed authentication function and made my own

```
remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
add_filter('authenticate', 'decrypt_and_authenticate', 10, 3);

function decrypt_and_authenticate($user, $username, $password) {
    // firs check if password needs to be decrypted
    if ($_REQUEST['encryption_code']) {

        // Obtenemos la clave DES usando nuestra clave privada RSA
        $key = new RSA(get_option('le_rsa_modulus'), get_option('le_rsa_public_key'), get_option('le_rsa_private_key'));
        $code = $key->decrypt($_REQUEST['encryption_code']); 

        // Obtenemos la clave usando la clave DES
        $pass = des ($code, hexToString($password), 0, 0, null, null);
        preg_match("/^([\s\w]*)/", $pass, $res);
        $password = $res[1];
        $_REQUEST['encryption_code'] = "";
    }

    if ( is_a($user, 'WP_User') ) { return $user; }

    if ( empty($username) || empty($password) ) {
        $error = new WP_Error();

        if ( empty($username) )
            $error->add('empty_username', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty.'));

        if ( empty($password) )
            $error->add('empty_password', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password field is empty.'));

        return $error;
    }

    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);

    if ( !$user )
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_username', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href="%s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ), wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        // Is user marked as spam?
        if ( 1 == $user->spam )
            return new WP_Error( 'spammer_account', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Your account has been marked as a spammer.' ) );

        // Is a user's blog marked as spam?
        if ( !is_super_admin( $user->ID ) && isset( $user->primary_blog ) ) {
            $details = get_blog_details( $user->primary_blog );
            if ( is_object( $details ) && $details->spam == 1 )
                return new WP_Error( 'blog_suspended', __( 'Site Suspended.' ) );
        }
    }

    $user = apply_filters('wp_authenticate_user', $user, $password);
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        return $user;

    if ( !wp_check_password($password, $user->user_pass, $user->ID) )
        return new WP_Error( 'incorrect_password', sprintf( __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>%1$s</strong> is incorrect. <a href="%2$s" title="Password Lost and Found">Lost your password</a>?' ),
        $username, wp_lostpassword_url() ) );

    return $user;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The things you can change in there are:

- `$secure_cookie = apply_filters('secure_signon_cookie', $secure_cookie, $credentials);` Cookie
- The `$credentials` for the `user_login` and `user_password`<sup>1)</sup>

Example

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'wpse119273UserCredentials' );
function wpse119273UserCredentials( $credentials )
{
    // Make sure to secure that value
    $credentials['user_password'] = 'foo';
}
```

To generate a secure password, take a look at the function [`wp_generate_password()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_generate_password/) and its internals. Or better: Make it even more secure.

<sup>1) As @brasofilo noted in the comment (I've overseen that). @brasofilo - Copy/Paste my answer to take it, it's your credits.</sup>

Comment: thank you for your answer but this does not work, strangly $credentials in function contain only "username", and this is not even an array, just a string.

when I dump inside wp_logon, everything is right and $credentials contain right iformation.

I think I'll update my question with more information

Comment: @Mpa4Hu _"I think I'll update my question with more information"_ ... Yeah, sure why not? _facepalm_

Comment: Sorry :D I just don't have much information, but I tried this return method and it didn't work. so I thought I ask it simple because I don't understand something )

Comment: Maybe add some context: Where and how are you using that function? In which cases does it fail? etc.